# convert from one time scale to another

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

i would like to exactly to convert  given scale of time into  years and month,suppose we have time 
$T = 2.35$ years
clearly  it is more then $2$ year,but what about $0.35$?in which scale it is given? In generally if it is related to year,then we should multiply it by  one year  or $12$ months to get in term of month what fraction it represent, but  could not it  given in days?then what is possible  scale for it? I need such kind of terms because maybe in GRE exam there could be such kind of transformation necessary,so please help me.

Comment: Years and months and days are all on the same scale, but using it is hazardous due to leap years and other anomalies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

$$
\begin{align}
2.35 \;\text{years} &= 2 \;\text{years} + 0.35 \;\text{years}\\ 
&= 2 \;\text{years} + 0.35 \frac{12 \;\text{months}}{1 \;\text{year}}\;\text{years}\\
&= 2 \;\text{years} + 4.2 \;\text{months}\\
&= 2 \;\text{years} + 4 \;\text{months} + 0.2 \frac{30 \;\text{days}}{1 \;\text{month}} \;\text{months}\\
&= 2 \;\text{years} + 4 \;\text{months} + 6 \;\text{days}
\end{align}
$$

Generally, when you write something like 22.35 years, the whole number is given in terms of the specified unit. In other words, the 0.35 is also measuring the amount in terms of years (I think that was part of your question.)

I can see why this might be confusing, though. We write time as hours:minutes, rather than hours:fraction-of-hours.

If you're ever in doubt about something like this on an exam, you can usually ask a prof. In any case, as long as you are very clear about what you're doing in your answer, and you provide steps that the markers can easily follow, you should be fine.

Comment: it is not  about  exam,in which prof can help,i mean it is not in classroom,but thanks very much,it is what i wanted

Comment: "months" are not a fixed unit, though; they vary obviously by month, and also by year.